# Does the order of calls to IEnumerable<T>-functions affect the final query when using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, ienumerable

In Entity framework, would the statement

```
MyDataContext.Products.OrderByDescending( (p) => p.Id ).GroupBy<Product,int>( (p) => p.ProductId ).Select( (g) => g.FirstOrDefault()).Where( (p) => p.Name.Equals("Something") );
```

result in another database query than

```
MyDataContext.Products.Where( (p) => p.Name.Equals("Something") ).OrderByDescending( (p) => p.Id ).GroupBy<Product,int>( (p) => p.ProductId ).Select( (g) => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

In other words, does the ordering of the calls to Where() and GroupBy() affect the final query to the db? Or is the entity framework smart enough to solve this?

The reason I wonder is that in the system I'm developing, we need to keep track of all changes to a product row. The solution we use in order to achieve this is to insert a new product row into the table rather than updating it. The different versions of a product is then grouped together by using the "ProductId"-field.  Thus, I would like to move the "Grouping"-logic out to an external method, but still allow the caller to specify the Where-conditions...so my aim is to use the first approach.

Comment: Why don't you use the a profiler tool (such as SQL Server profiler) to see what's the difference in the executed queries?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that was actually my first idea, but I don't have enough privileges on the SQL Server...but I could always install a local copy of the db on a SQL Server Express and try it that way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's important. [The EF may silently ignore `OrderBy` calls which come before `Where` calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#OrderingInfoLost). This shouldn't be terribly surprising, since SQL queries don't support `ORDER BY` before `WHERE` *at all*, outside of a subquery.

Note that you can still "move the 'Grouping'-logic out to an external method, but still allow the caller to specify the Where-conditions," even with this consideration:

```
var q = SomeQuery
        .Where(GeneratePredicate())
        .GroupBy(GenerateSelector<string>());
```

Where you have methods like:

```
public Expresssion<Func<SomeEntity, bool>> GeneratePredicate
{
     return e => e.Id == 123;
}

public Expression<Func<SomeEntity, T>> GenerateSelector<T>()
{
     return e => e.GroupField;
}
```

Importantly, these `Where` and `GroupBy` calls are **not** methods of `IEnumerable<T>`; they're methods of `IQueryable<T>`, which is why they can be converted to SQL at all.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer! Hmm...the call to OrderByDescending() is done since I want to retrieve  the correct (or last) version of the product. Then I simply pick the first item in the group to get it right. Do you mean that this ordering could be ignored if I call Where after? Haven't thought of that so thank you for the tip!

Comment: Yes, it does. You might want to use `First(Expression)` instead of `OrderBy().First()`.